# Percentage for each result where id = id

Tags: php, html, for-loop, mysqli, sum

In my database i have a table wich looks like this:

[image: How my database looks]

Now, in my php code i make a SUM like this:

```
function number_of_axless() {
        $sql = "SELECT (sum(distance))/(25000)*(100) as totaldistance1 FROM axle WHERE train_id = :train_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(':train_id', $_GET['train_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

And:

```
<?php
    $number_of_axles = $database->number_of_axless();

    foreach($number_of_axles as $number_ofaxles){
        echo $number_ofaxles['totaldistance1'];
    }
?>
```

Now i get the result: 40. (40%)

but what i want is that is shows me 4 results. with 4 different numbers.

So:

> axle 1 = 0 so it should be 0%
>   axle 2 = 2500 so it should be 10%
>   axle 3 = 5000 so it should be 30%
>   axle 4 = 2500 so it should be 40%

How do i do this?

Right now all the axles are 40%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the sum in php cycle, not in sql (the ORDER BY clause is also important here):

```
$sql = "SELECT distance FROM axle WHERE train_id = :train_id ORDER BY axle ASC";

...

$total_distance = 0;
foreach($number_of_axles as $number_ofaxles){
    $total_distance += $number_ofaxles['distance'];
    echo $total_distance/25000*100;
}
```